# DropDownList can't bind to DbNull

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, dbnull

I have a DropDownList trying to bind to DbNull and it's not happy about it. I've seen advice about creating a ListItem with value=" " but this isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should add that this is conditional: the bind works as expected when the value is not DbNull.

Comment: Can you explain "not happy about"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add default value to dropdwon list you can do it as below

```
 mydropdown.DataSource = getdata();
 mydropdown.DataBind();
 mydropdown.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("N/A","N/A"));
```

**Edit**

if you know some values of the datasouce is null than y dont you filter out those value at database level and than bind soruce with the drop down.
or
make use of `Isnull()` in query and assing default value to null values.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work to bound DBNull while the other items are e.g. of type int.
With a white space or empty string I got problems too. So best way would be to change your DBNull entry with a constant value, that would not appear in your database and have the same data type like the other entries, for example -1.